# How to style multiple lists in columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have a number x of unordered lists ().

My working solution for 2 columns now is:

```
<div class="catalog_menu_widget">
<ul>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM</li>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM</li>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM</li>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM</li>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM</li>
    <li>LOREM IPSUM</li>
</ul>
</div>

.catalog_menu_widget {
    width: 820px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #e4e8fe;
    float: left;
}

.catalog_menu_widget ul {
    width: 410px;
    float: left;
}

.catalog_menu_widget li {
    line-height: 25px;
}

.catalog_menu_widget a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #003769; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
}
```

Now my question is, which css styling do I need to achieve a flexible multi-column layout?
3 ULs displayed in 3 cols, 4 ULs displayed in 4 cols, ...
I have already googled for it, but most of the solutions are CSS3 or for 2-columns only and we just want to support IE8 (which has no CSS3) and furthermore it is important that the markup (multiple ULs) is a prequisite and can't be touched.

Thanks in advance for your help!

edit:

**Solution**:

```
var width = 100 / jQuery('.catalog_menu_widget ul').length;
jQuery('.catalog_menu_widget ul').css({width: width + '%'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tagged `jquery`, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $width = 100 / $('.catalog_menu_widget ul').length;
    $('.catalog_menu_widget ul').css({width: $width + '%'});
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YA77j/)

Comment: thank you! works for me. I took your code and put it into my starting-post under "solution".

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAp96/3/). Setting the `min-width` property also allows the layout to be responsive.

The jQuery is superfluous if you want to manually enter the `Li` width % values.

CSS

```
h2 {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.cols li{
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class='cols'>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
var cols=3;
$('.cols li').css({width:+100/cols+'%'});
```